# "An error has occurred. See the log file.." problem to install eclipse on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse

I installed eclipse on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS but can't open ecilpse. An error message pop up.

error message:

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file /home/sumon/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1582634683890.log
```

[image: error message]

log file:

```
sumon@sumon-Vostro-1450:~$ cat /home/sumon/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1582634683890.log
!SESSION Tue Feb 25 18:44:43 BDT 2020 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2020-02-25 18:44:43.927
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

[image: following .log file]

How to solve this problem?
I like to mention that I installed another version of eclipse before and uninstall this.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please edit your question and copy and paste the error from the log file instead of posting a screenshot. This helps so people can google the error to figure out the problem. When you edit your question, paste the error into the question, highlight the code, and then press CTRL+K to automatically format the error as code and then click "save edits". Thanks!

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author.